# Every Cauchy sequence converges in a compact metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, cauchy-sequences

So, I understand what a compact metric space is but I don't really have an intuition as to why that means that every Cauchy sequence converges in a compact metric space.

Is there a good way to intuitively understand this theorem or should I just keep reworking the proof?

Comment: Do you understand why decreasing nests of closed sets in a compact metric space have non-empty intersection?

Comment: If you use the sequentially compact definition (which is equivalent to compactness in a metric space), then the proof is quite easy: Take a Cauchy sequence in the compact metric space. Since the space is (sequentially) compact, this sequence has a convergent subsequence. But then, it is an easy exercise to show that a Cauchy sequence with a convergent subsequence is itself convergent!

Comment: Thank you both! I am unsure of what you mean when you say decreasing nests of closed sets.

Comment: @GeorginaSpence: A family $\{F_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ of closed sets such that $F_n\supseteq F_{n-1}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. (It’s actually enoug to have a family $\mathscr{C}$ of closed sets such that $\bigcap\mathscr{F}\ne\varnothing$ for each finite $\mathscr{F}\subseteq\mathscr{C}$.)

Comment: I understand it in two steps. First of all, any infinite subset of a compact spacemust accumulate somewhere. Then, when you consider this infinite subset to be your sequence $(x_n)$, you will find a convergent subsequence. 

The second thing is that any Cauchy sequence which has a convergent subsequence must already converge. Namely, terms that are far enough along in the sequence are close to points of the subsequence, which in term are close to their limiting value. (I'm sketching the $2\epsilon$-argument.)